# Solve an Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

Can anyone help me integrate $$\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}dx$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is this integral coming from?  If this is coming from a class, what tools might you be able to apply?

Comment: Try integrate it using 'integrate by parts' formula: $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx = f(x) \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx + \int_{a}^{b} \frac{df}{dx}\left(\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx\right)dx$.

Comment: Throw the integral to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5Bx%5E2%2F%28Exp%5Bx%5D%2B1%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D), it returns

$$\frac32\zeta(3) + 1 - \log(1+e) + 2{\rm Li}_2(-\frac1{e}) _+ 2{\rm Li}_3(-\frac1{e})$$ Are you supposed to know the [polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) ${\rm Li}_s(z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I(x)=\int \frac{x^2}{e^x+1} dx = \int x^2 \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} dx = \int \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}  x^2 e^{-kx} dx$$
$$I(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{2-2kx+k^2x^2}{k^3} e^{kx}$$ $$\implies I(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}-x^2\ln (1+e^{x})-2x \text{Li}_2(-e^{-x})+2\text{Li}_3(-e^{-x})$$

Comment: I think you solve the wrong integral, because the denominator is e^x + 1

Comment: Thanks I have corrected it now..